# Custom tag like google used for social plug in

Tags: html

i want to know about this custom tag that google use for social plug in

I have added +1 button to my web site have this custom code

```
<g:plusone href="https://plus.google.com/----------1212"></g:plusone>
```

**----------1212** is id of Google page

how we can create this type of custom tag for our page

like `<g:plusone />` is a tag how we can create custome like `<mytag />` or other

Comment: Just do it. What problems are you encountering?

Comment: no problem but i want to know that how we can this type of custom tag

Comment: like <g:plusone/> is a tag how we can create custome like <mytag /> or other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way would be to use jQuery. This example will turn <mytag> into a  large, red heading. You can all kinds of other stuff, such as adding images.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('mytag').each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith('<span style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: red;">' + $(this).html() + '</span>');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<mytag>This is a large, red font</mytag>
```